# How to write dataframe to csv, while updating and dropping duplicates in csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I can successfully drop duplicates and update rows in an existing dataframe. When I write this dataframe too a csv that already has data in it, how do I do the same commands in the dataframe to the csv to drop duplicates and update rows.

```
df:
ID       email      date
0        a@a.com    2018-01-22
1        b@b.com    2018-01-20

csv:
ID       email      date
0        d@d.com    2018-01-22
```

I need the csv to look like this:

```
csv:
ID       email      date
0        a@a.com    2018-01-22
1        b@b.com    2018-01-20
```

This is my code for pandas to drop and update in the dataframe:

```
permanent=permanent.sort_values(['ID']).drop_duplicates(['ID'],keep='last')
```

Not sure how to do the pandas line for the csv.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: why does [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) not work in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
# filename containing data
filename = 'file.csv'

# drop duplicates from existing dataframe
permanent = permanent.sort_values('ID')\
                     .drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')

# read file into dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

# concatenate the above dataframes and drop duplicates
new_df = pd.concat([permanent, df], ignore_index=True)\
           .sort_values('ID')\
           .drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')

# write to file
new_df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I referenced this script and was getting an UnboundLocalError... 'permanent' referenced before assignment

I believe the line should be

permanent - filename.sort...etc.

That worked for my data.

```
# filename containing data
filename = 'file.csv'

# drop duplicates from existing dataframe
permanent = filename.sort_values('ID')\
                     .drop_duplicates('ID', keep='last')
```